# http request values are empty if the request is passed by value

Tags: go

Could someone explains what's happening here?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func Verify(req http.Request) string {
    return req.FormValue("g-recaptcha-response")
}

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://www.google.com/search?q=foo&q=bar&both=x&prio=1&empty=not",
        strings.NewReader("z=post&both=y&prio=2&empty="))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; param=value")
    Verify(*req)
    fmt.Println(req.FormValue("z"))
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/ve4Cc_JTzr)

This will produce an empty output.
Now if I access the value "z" *before* passing the request as value, it works!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func Verify(req http.Request) string {
    return req.FormValue("g-recaptcha-response")
}

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://www.google.com/search?q=foo&q=bar&both=x&prio=1&empty=not",
        strings.NewReader("z=post&both=y&prio=2&empty="))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; param=value")
    Verify(*req)
    fmt.Println(req.FormValue("z"))
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/5ALnt-pHTl)

I have tried with several versions of go from 1.5 to 1.7, with the same odd result.
If the request is passed by reference, it's working as expected.

Comment: 1. There is no "pass by reference" in Go. 2. Never copy a http.Request. 3. Work with *http.Request only.

Comment: I agree, but I'm using a lib doing this (https://github.com/haisum/recaptcha/blob/master/recaptcha.go#L46). And that doesn't explain what I see :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because Request's body is `io.Reader`, and you can read from `io.Reader` only once, when you try to read content second time, there is no more data to read.

Method `FormValue` calls `ParseForm`, and it reads all data from the reader.

Comment: In other words, you can fix this in a generalized way by calling `req.ParseForm()` before doing anything with the request.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. So the body being read "for the copy" is no more available for the original request, hence the empty string. Thanks!